# Is this a plot hole?

Tags: licanius

Wirr is able to use his powers on an echo when he thinks it is a human. Which seems to say that reality is what determines the tenets bindings.

But,

> Administrator Ionis attempts to force Torin to change the Tenets to force all Gifted to kill themselves. Torin says that the tenets would prevent him from doing this. But Ionis says the tenets allow for personal interpretation.

I love the story but this is bothering me.